# TFS 2015 Build: PowerTools - Unable to determine workspace

Tags: powershell, build, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, tfs-power-tools

For our TFS 2015 vNext Build system I'm trying to check-out/edit/check-in a file with a PowerShell script.

Currently the following lines are called within a custom Build-Step:

```
#checkout file
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $localVersionPath -lock none -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -wa 0
#edit item
#[...]
#checkin file
New-TfsChangeset -Item $localVersionPath -Verbose -Comment "***NO_CI*** - Updating Version.Registry" -Override true
```

The variable `$localVersionPath` is set correctly to the file I want to checkout..

while executing those lines, the TFS-agent replies following line twice in live console:

> Unable to determine the workspace.

When calling the checkout/checkin command on a command-prompt on our buildserver, everything works just fine, but in build-environment I get the error above..

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I think the issue is because in the new build system for TFS 2015 all communication with the server is done as the Project Collection or Project Build service account depending on how you have configured the definition.  

When you are running your PowerShell that is running as the user the agent is running under so the workspace used by the build is not owned by the agent user.  I am not sure how to get around that in powershell unless you can pass the Oauth token from the build into your cmdlets.

Comment: Can this script works with the XAML build?

Comment: How did you set the $localVersionPath? Set it to local workspace?

Comment: Having the same issue. If you list the workspaces on the build server using `tf workspaces /s:<tfsServerUri>` it says the workspace for the build is owned by "Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)" but the service is running as "mydomain\tfsbuild". This was working until we upgraded TFS from 2015 to 2017 a couple of weeks ago